# BeautiFulSoup4 не могу вытащить номер lalafo в Exel файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

не могу разобраться в чем проблема, автор сообщил что ранее код работал на момент заливки, но сейчас он не может мне помочь решить проблемку, сам не смог, прошу помощи.

https://github.com/Codyusey/lalafo_kg_parser

При запуске никаких ошибок нет, выдает только это:

……… lalafo_kg parser's started ……

Error get data https://lalafo.kg/bishkek/kvartiry/prodazha-kvartir?sort_by=default&page=0

……… Error has occurred. Please restart the script. ……

Помогите плиз. что не так...? Мне нужно вытащить только номера тел.

```
"""
One-thread parser  https://lalafo.kg/bishkek/kvartiry/prodazha-kvartir/
Parsing speed approximately ~ 120 items/s.
OS: Windows 10
"""

import json
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import pytz
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
from random import randrange
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from winsound import MessageBeep, MB_OK, MB_ICONHAND
from tqdm import tqdm
import cursor

colorama.init(autoreset=True)
current_data_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
current_data = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
abspath_workdir = os.path.dirname((os.path.abspath(__file__)))

headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;'
                     '=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ('
                         'KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

header_items = ["Number", "Advert id", "Advert url", "Main mobile phone", "Messenger phone_1",
                "Messenger phone_2", "Messenger phone_3", "Messenger phone 4", "Advert title", "Price",
                "Currency", "Created time", "Updated_time"]
MESS_LEN = 90
items_dict = {}
pagination = 0


def get_pag_data(page):
    """ Get pagination for start loop. Get data json"""
    global pagination
    url = f'https://lalafo.kg/bishkek/kvartiry/prodazha-kvartir?sort_by=default&page={str(page)}'
    count = 0
    while count <= 2:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            try:
                response = session.get(url=url, headers=headers)
                time.sleep(randrange(1, 2))
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
                data_str_like_json = soup.find('script', id="__NEXT_DATA__", type="application/json").text
                data_dict = json.loads(data_str_like_json)
                if page == 0:
                    pagination = int(data_dict['props']['initialState']['listing']['listingFeed']["_meta"]['pageCount'])
                    return pagination
                else:
                    return data_dict
            except Exception:
                print_ln(f'Error get data {url}', tab_type='', start_ln='\r',  end_ln='', color=Fore.RED)
            if count == 2:
                print_ln("Error has occurred. Please restart the script.", color=Fore.RED)
                beep(b_type=MB_ICONHAND)
                sys.exit()
            count += 1


def parser_json():
    """Scraping pages and save to xls file"""
    pre_id = 0
    for page in tqdm(range(1, get_pag_data(0) + 1), desc='Scraping pages', unit='page', ncols=MESS_LEN,
                     bar_format="{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (Fore.GREEN, Fore.RESET)):
        data_dict = get_pag_data(page)
        for key in data_dict['props']['initialState']['listing']['listingFeed']['items']:
            items_lists = [''] * len(header_items)
            items_lists[1] = key['id']
            items_lists[2] = 'https://lalafo.kg' + key['url']
            try:
                items_lists[3] = "tel:" + key['mobile']
            except:
                items_lists[3] = ''
            try:
                items_lists[4] = "tel:" + key['user']['business']['features']['contact_phones']['model']['contacts'][0][
                    'phone']
            except:
                items_lists[4] = ''
            try:
                items_lists[5] = "tel:" + key['user']['business']['features']['contact_phones']['model']['contacts'][1][
                    'phone']
            except:
                items_lists[5] = ''
            try:
                items_lists[6] = "tel:" + key['user']['business']['features']['contact_phones']['model']['contacts'][2][
                    'phone']
            except:
                items_lists[6] = ''
            try:
                items_lists[7] = "tel:" + key['user']['business']['features']['contact_phones']['model']['contacts'][3][
                    'phone']
            except:
                items_lists[7] = ''
            items_lists[8] = key['title']
            try:
                items_lists[9] = key['price']
                items_lists[10] = key['currency']
            except:
                items_lists[9] = ''
                items_lists[10] = ''
            city_timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Bishkek")  # local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
            items_lists[11] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                key['created_time'], city_timezone).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            items_lists[12] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                key['updated_time'], city_timezone).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            if pre_id != key['id']:
                pre_id = key['id']
            items_dict[key['id']] = items_lists

    for num, key in enumerate(items_dict):
        items_dict[key][0] = num + 1
    print_ln(f'Quantity of parsed items: ', start_ln='', tab_type='', end_ln='', color=Fore.GREEN)
    print_ln(f'{len(items_dict)}', start_ln='', tab_type='')  # color = Fore.WHITE


def write_items_xlsx(name_xlsx, data_dict_, header_list_):
    """ write data to xlsx file"""
    work_book_ = Workbook()
    work_cell = work_book_.active
    work_cell.column_dimensions['A'].width = len(header_list_[0])
    work_cell.column_dimensions['B'].width = len(header_list_[1]) + 5
    work_cell.column_dimensions['C'].width = len(header_list_[2]) + 7
    work_cell.column_dimensions['D'].width = len(header_list_[3]) + 3
    work_cell.column_dimensions['E'].width = len(header_list_[4]) + 2
    work_cell.column_dimensions['F'].width = len(header_list_[5]) + 2
    work_cell.column_dimensions['G'].width = len(header_list_[6]) + 2
    work_cell.column_dimensions['H'].width = len(header_list_[7]) + 2
    work_cell.column_dimensions['I'].width = len(header_list_[8]) + 12
    work_cell.column_dimensions['J'].width = len(header_list_[9]) + 2
    work_cell.column_dimensions['K'].width = len(header_list_[10])
    work_cell.column_dimensions['L'].width = len(header_list_[11]) + 4
    work_cell.column_dimensions['M'].width = len(header_list_[12]) + 4
    work_cell.title = f'lalafo_kg_{len(data_dict_)}itm_{current_data}'
    if header_list_ != "":
        work_cell.append(header_list_)
    if len(data_dict_) != 0:
        for row in data_dict_.values():
            work_cell.append(row)
        for cell in work_cell["1:1"]:
            cell.font = Font(bold=True)
        work_book_.save(name_xlsx)
    else:
        print_ln('Noting to write. Data is empty', start_ln='', tab_type='*', color=Fore.GREEN)


def print_ln(message, tab_type='…', start_ln='\n', end_ln='\n', color=Fore.WHITE):
    """ Print messages in line"""
    mess_len = MESS_LEN
    if len(tab_type) == 0:
        spc = ""
    else:
        spc = " "
    tab_len = int((mess_len - 2 - len(message)) / 2)
    print(color + start_ln + tab_type * tab_len + spc + message + spc + " " * (
            len(message) % 2) + tab_type * tab_len, end=end_ln)


def beep(times=1, b_type=MB_OK):
    """Sound notifications"""
    for _ in range(times):
        MessageBeep(b_type)
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    """Run parser"""
    cursor.hide()

    print_ln("lalafo_kg parser's started", color=Fore.GREEN)
    parser_json()
    xlsx_pathname = 'lalafo_kg_' + str(len(items_dict)) + 'items_' + current_data_time + '.xlsx'
    write_items_xlsx(xlsx_pathname, items_dict, header_items)
    print_ln('End', start_ln='', color=Fore.GREEN)
    beep(3)
    os.startfile(abspath_workdir)
    os.startfile(xlsx_pathname)
    cursor.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```